# Ajax loading HTML form is closing directly

Tags: html, ajax, forms, smarty, loading

I am loading an Ajax form with Smarty and jQuery.

It should load this:

```
{foreach $topFEED as $article}
    <tr>
        <td><form action='postbox.php' method='POST'></td>
        <td><img class="favicon_prev" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain={$article.img_link}">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="link" style="width: 300px;" value="{$article.link}" READONLY/></td>
        {if $loggedin}<td><input type='submit' id="abo" name="submit" value='Abonnieren' /></td>
            <input type='hidden' name="action" value='add_feed' READONLY />{/if}
        <td></form></td>
    </tr>
{/foreach}
```

Ajax Code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "article.php?method=top_feeds",
        dataType: 'html',
    })
    .done(function(html) {
        $("#ajax_top_feeds").replaceWith(html);
    });
```

Result:

```
 <tr>
        <td><form action="postbox.php" method="POST"></form></td>
        <td><img class="favicon_prev" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=http://www.n-tv.de">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="link" style="width: 300px;" value="http://www.n-tv.de/rss" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="abo" name="submit" value="Abonnieren"></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_feed" readonly="">            <td></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid, the browser is simply correcting it for you.  `form` elements can't cross multiple table cells like that.

You can wrap a `form` around your entire `table`:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <!--- etc. --->
    </table>
</form>
```

Or you can place a `form` inside of a table cell:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form>
                <!--- etc. --->
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But you can't begin a form in one cell and end it in another.  The hierarchy of HTML markup isn't structured that way.  Tags must be closed before parent tags are closed.

Comment: Oh okay :D yap Thanks